# Is a bounded sequence to some power also a bounded sequence

Tags: calculus, set-theory

Let sequence ${(x_{n})}$ be a bounded sequence and let ${(y_{n})}$ be equal to ${(x_{n})^{-1/3}}$. Is ${(y_{n})}$ then also bounded?

So I know that ${(x_{n})}$ being bounded means that there is some number A so that ${|x_{i}| \le A}$ holds true for every i. Intuitively, I think that ${(y_{n})}$ will be bounded but how can I proof this? I've thought about a proof by contradiction but can't seem to set it up.

Comment: Hint: what happens if you consider $x_n := \dfrac{1}{n^3}$ for example?

Comment: For the boundedness of $x_n^{-1/3}$ you need that $|x_n|$ is bounded away from $0.$ The boundedness of $x_n$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t true. As a counterexample, we could have the sequence $a_n = 1/n$ which is bounded by $1$, but the sequence $b_n = a_n^{-1/2}$ is simply $b_n = \sqrt{n}$ which is unbounded. The same would be true if my power was $-1/3$

Comment: Guess my intuition was wrong. Thank you!